# Deploying a Nodejs app to Windows without IIS and without a private key

Tags: node.js, express, https, ssl-certificate

I've read a tonne of articles on the web and looked at a tonne of questions on stack overflow related to the following, and they all provide basically the same solution which I am unable to implement due to security issues with my company.

I am trying to deploy a NodeJS app to a secure windows server without IIS.  I'm not even sure if this is possible - there is very little support about deploying node apps to windows, and what support there is says to use IIS and iisnode together.  To add to the complication, my company will not give me the key to the main SSL certificate of the server.

I have access to the server/cert store/certificate, but I can't export its key.  Just wondering if there is a way to have server.js point to just the certificate instead of both the certificate AND the key?

I've tried to access the certificate and extract the key via https://www.npmjs.com/package/win-ca but haven't had any luck with this.

I was able to use a self-signed certificate and get everything working, but you need to accept the self-signed certificate in your browser which isn't a viable solution for production.

I've also looked into using nginx, let's encrypt, etc., but windows support for those isn't that great either.

Here is my code which works, but like I said, I need to accept the self-signed cert client side which isn't ideal:

```
const express = require('express');  
const app = express();  
const https = require('https');  
const http = require('http');  
const fs = require('fs');  

const options = {  
//self-signed cert, I'd rather point this to the main cert for the server  
//but I don't have access to the key  
  key: fs.readFileSync('cert.key'),  
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem'),  
};  

// Create an HTTP service.  
http.createServer(app).listen(80);  

// Create an HTTPS service identical to the HTTP service.  
https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);  

app.get('/', function (req, res) {  
    res.send('Hello World!');  
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end I removed all the certificate and security related stuff from my server.js file and just put the website behind a load balancing proxy server.

Comment: would you care to expand about the proxy server an configuration you used?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot.  When I said "I", I should have said our devops teams did it all.  I'm not too familiar with that side of things.  Sorry.